# Does realm need nested objects to be added explicitly

Tags: swift, realm

Consider two models:

```
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String
    @objc dynamic var pet: Animal
}

class Animal: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String
}
```

Now if I had to create and add new Person with a Pet. Is following is sufficient?

```
realm.write{
    let dog = Animal(name: "Daisy")
    let person = Person(name: "John Wick", pet: dog)
    
    realm.add(person)     // <----- This

}
```

Or I need to explicitly add dog(Nested Object) too?

```
realm.write{
    let dog = Animal(name: "Daisy")
    let person = Person(name: "John Wick", pet: dog)
    
    realm.add(person)
    realm.add(dog)     // <----- Like This

}
```

Comment: What you have there is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sufficient

```
realm.write{
    let dog = Animal(name: "Daisy")
    let person = Person(name: "John Wick", pet: dog)
    
    realm.add(person)     // <----- This

}
```

The **Animal** object will be inserted automatically , just make a query for that model and you will get it